# When using Absolute Error in Gradient Descent, how to calculate the derivative?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, regression, linear-regression

What is the derivative of the Loss Function (Absolute Error) with respect to the feature weights that is used to update the weights?

Couldn't find anything specific about it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gradient of MAE is not continuous in $y_{pred} = y_{true}$ and therefore there is no defined (bounded, direction independent) derivative at that point.

Elsewhere you have -1, where  $y_{pred} > y_{true}$ and +1 where  $y_{pred} < y_{true}$

Usually frameworks like TensorFlow, Keras, etc... use an approximate derivative for that point.

Comment: If I want to compute a simple regression where I will be updating the weights by differentiating the Loss w.r.t the weight vector, how do I implement it? When I did it by hand, I took two different cases on whether y_{pred} > y_{true} and accordingly, beta_{0} = beta_{0} +- learning_rate/(number of samples) and beta_{1} = beta_{1} +- learning_rate*features/(number of samples). I have a bias term and 1 feature.

Comment: May help someone who is having the same question: I used a grid search to try different combinations of the two weights. Much slower than gradient descent in MSE.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly...to do it by hand you would have to differentiate (by approximation) your error for each component. Meaning for a network with 1 Input, 1 Hidden Node and 1 Output: de/dw, de/dI, de/db, de/dy

Comment: Going by page 360 of Elements of Statistical Learning, the gradient for absolute error loss is $\textrm{sign}[y_i - f(x_i)]$. The sign function _is_ defined at 0, it is 0. So when $y_{pred} = y_{true}$, the gradient would equal 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply [approximate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1172480/487106) $f(x)=|x|$ by $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+c}$ where $c>0$.
You can also utilize [subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) method.